# How to access SOAP 1.1 fault detail from WCF client (no fault contract)

Tags: wcf, soap

I'm accessing a SOAP 1.1 web service, and it's returning a fault.  The web service does not define any fault contract in the WSDL as far as I can see.  My WCF client maps the fault to a FaultException (rather than a FaultException<T>).  This all makes sense.  The problem is that the service is returning some useful diagnostic information in the detail element of the fault, which I'd like to access so that I can dump it to a trace log.   It seems that FaultException does not provide any access to the detail element, presumably because without a fault contract it doesn't know what is in there.

But I don't need to deserialize the detail XML - just the raw XML as a string will do fine for diagnostic purposes.

Is there any way to get access to the detail XML from a WCF client, in this scenario?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As detailed here:
http://www.theruntime.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/01/28/getting-at-the-details.aspx

you can use this workaround to obtain the details:

```
} catch (FaultException soapEx)
{    
    MessageFault mf = soapEx.CreateMessageFault();    
    if (mf.HasDetail)
    {    
        XmlDictionaryReader reader = mf.GetReaderAtDetailContents();    
        ...    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I'd give you +10 if it was possible.. I just *remebered* it was somewhere, but I was unable to find that even on MSDN API dump. Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
You can then iterate through data by doing: while (reader.Read()) { }
and access the data inside the loop through reader.Name and reader.Value