# Consuming non-wcf SOAP fault from WCF client (soap fault defined)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-client

I have a non-wcf server that I call from WCF client and I need to gain access to registered soap fault in case server throws it (it contains a feedback I need for user). I used the example from [How to access SOAP 1.1 fault detail from WCF client (no fault contract)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134658/518649) but its a pain given I DO have the fault contract defined in the wsdl, at least per SOAP specification and the fault contains error code and error string.

```
<wsdl:types>
    <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.cisco.com/BTS10200/i01" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        ...
        <complexType name="BtsSoapException">
            <sequence>
                <element name="error_code" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="error_string" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <element name="fault" type="impl:BtsSoapException"/>
...

<wsdl:message name="BtsSoapException">
    <wsdl:part element="impl:fault" name="fault"/>
</wsdl:message>
...

<wsdl:portType name="Bts10200Operations">
    <wsdl:operation name="login">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:loginRequest" name="loginRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:loginResponse" name="loginResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:BtsSoapException" name="BtsSoapException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
...
```

The service import recognizes all this properly and generates proper code constructs:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="BtsSoapException", Namespace="http://www.cisco.com/BTS10200/i01")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class BtsSoapException : object ...

....

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://www.cisco.com/BTS10200/i01", ConfigurationName="CiscoBTSService.Bts10200Operations")]
public interface Bts10200Operations {
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(TestCiscoBTS.CiscoBTSService.BtsSoapException), Action="", Name="fault")]
    TestCiscoBTS.CiscoBTSService.loginResponse login(TestCiscoBTS.CiscoBTSService.loginRequest request);
...
```

When I call the `login()` with invalid account I DO get proper response as per wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
            <faultstring></faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:fault xmlns:ns1="http://www.cisco.com/BTS10200/i01">
                    <error_code>401</error_code>
                    <error_string xsi:type="xsd:string">java.lang.Exception: No user profile defined in the database for fakeuser</error_string>
                </ns1:fault>
                <ns2:exceptionName xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">com.sswitch.oam.soap.intf.BtsSoapException</ns2:exceptionName>
                <ns3:stackTrace xmlns:ns3="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
    at com.sswitch.oam.soap.impl.UserAuth.validateUser(UserAuth.java:63)
    ...
```

The `FaultExcpetion` does fire, however its blank (`Message` = "") and I do not see any property exposing BtsSoapException instance. Like it hasn't been deserialized at all (even though wcf knows everything it needs to do it). What am I doing wrong? How do I make WCF give me `FaultException<BtsSoapException>`?

Comment: Do you have the FaultContract attribute showing on the operation in the service contract?

Comment: Sorry it is there. Missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your tried doing something like the code shown below, you need to catch the specific soap fault contract that has the information you are looking for. The information in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx) should help.

```
var proxy = new WhatEverYourServiceProxyClassIsNamed();
try
{
    //your call logic here

    proxy.Close();
}
catch (FaultException<BtsSoapException> bse)
{
    //Get the info you're looking for in the strongly typed soap fault:

    proxy.Abort();
}
catch (FaultException fe)
{
    //Do something appropriate for a non-typed soap fault

    proxy.Abort();
}
finally
{
    if ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).State != CommunicationState.Closed)
        proxy.Abort();
}
```

Comment: The problem is not my catching, the problem is that WCF does not throw `FaultException<BtsSoapException>` even though the fault contract is specified, it only throws `FaultException`

Comment: Then the issue is a "disconnect" in the deserialization of the soap fault by WCF and the definition of the TestCiscoBTS.CiscoBTSService.BtsSoapException class generated by your Add Reference/SvcUtil process. To troubleshoot this, try creating a simple WCF service with a strongly typed fault contract and ensure you can trigger that fault in the service code. Call the service, generate the fault and verify the client can catch that specific fault. Lastly, compare what the fault looks like in the soap XML with the fault XML in this question. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) You may have to modify the generated proxy fault contract to match the serialized XML sent but your java service. You should also look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733841.aspx) because there are some limitations in how WCF supports soap fault definition (see the last section of the article).

Comment: As far as I could see it matches, the only thing I see out of the ordinary is presence of Java related exceptionName and stackTrace, but thse detail pieces are in different namespace (`http://xml.apache.org/axis/`). Could this be a bug in WCF that parser fails unless detail schema is 1-1 against the fault response? I will definitely try to create a wcf service that faults in BtsException and see what comes back...

Comment: Well, the output matches the one I get from the service, sans the java details. So my conclusion at this point is that WCF fails to deserialize fault if fault contains more info than is defined by WSDL. I think this classifies as a bug since XML specification states that you should IGNORE surplus XML fragments in other namespaces and I'll post this on connect. As for this topic, since bounty timeout is in half an hour and I don't think there is a viable solution I'll accept your answer and give you bounty for pointing me towards diagnostic process. Shame for hard earned points to go to waste.

Comment: Thanks for being so gracious!! Today happens to be my birthday so I'll consider it a present from StackOverflow.

Comment: I stumbled upon same problem and have noticed that details inside the fault are not seen. Did you ever got any work around to this problem?

Comment: TL;DR: No workarounds exist.

I dusted off the cobwebs on this and I believe these issues are all related to XML (not .NET) namespaces. The answer provided by jlvaquero hints at this problem: the response XML shows the 'fault' element is defined in namespace 'ns1'. The 'error_code' & 'error_string' elements belong to whatever the default XML namespace is at this point. It could be empty or some java defined namespace. If WCF is only mapping declared fault contract namespaces, then any elements not defined in them will be ignored at best or cause the fault serialization to fail at worst.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sixto Saez is right. You can see the BtsSoapException instance inside of the FaultException.

Definition:

```
<complexType name="BtsSoapException">
    <sequence>
        <element name="error_code" type="xsd:int"/>
        <element name="error_string" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Response:

```
<detail>
    <ns1:fault xmlns:ns1="http://www.cisco.com/BTS10200/i01">
        <error_code>401</error_code>
        <error_string xsi:type="xsd:string">java.lang.Exception: No user profile defined in the database for fakeuser</error_string>
```

if you do

```
catch (FaultException<BtsSoapException> bse)
{
    console.write(bse.Detail.error_string)
}
```

you must see "java.lang.Exception: No user profile defined in the database for fakeuser" in the output window when you are debugging.

Comment: Nope, trust me, thats the first thing I did. I even inspected the exception type to be sure and its pure `FaultException`, not the inherited `FaultException<T>`. Just for sanity sake I even created a cascaded catch like the one Sixto Saez posted and it skips the generic version and stops on non-generic parent. If it were that simple I wouldn't have posted the bounty on it :)

Comment: Ugg!! Weird thing. Try adding the Namespace attribute to the FaultContractAttribute.  [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(TestCiscoBTS.CiscoBTSService.BtsSoapException), Action="", Name="fault", Namespace="http://www.cisco.com/BTS10200/i01")]

Comment: Arg!! StackOverflow engine parses the namespace URI in comments. Well I think you'll catch the point...

Comment: Well, it has the namespace defined in `DataContract` for `BtsSoapException`. Still, I tried what you suggest and it didn't help. I don't think its the issue with service discovery, I now believe its a bug in WCF.

Comment: I started to think the same but many of bugs has stupid solutions like the one I suggested.